# In Adding a Controller Visual Studio 2019 Creates a ts file instead of cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I recently installed Visual studio 2019 and when I attempt to create a Controller I get a typescript file instead.

[image]

I overwrite the default name file.ts with productscontroller.cs

[image]

I get an empty ts file and not a template for a controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go into the directory of visual studio installed.

[image]

In the folder ItemTemplates, it contains the sources for the item templates you use inside Visual Studio.

2. If the first solution cannot solve it. It may be missing some settings, reimport setting.

Open *Tool -> Import and Export Settings*, select **Import selected environment settings** and click Next, then select **No,just import new settings, overwriting my current setting**. Click *Browse* to select the *.vssettings*.